# Cannot access function by name inside ajaxComplete?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function that works fine in $(ready):

```
var externalLink = $("a[href*='/domain.com'], a[href*='.domain.com']");
function externalLinkFix(){
    if((externalLink).hasClass("foo")) {
        $(externalLink).removeClass("foo").addClass("bar").off('click');
    } else {
        $(externalLink).addClass("bar");
    }
}

$(function(){
    externalLinkFix();
});
```

However, when I call it in the ajaxComplete call it does nothing.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){
    externalLinkFix();
});
```

I have to include the functions contents inside the ajaxComplete. Why can't I access the function itself by name?

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){
    if((externalLink).hasClass("foo")) {
        $(externalLink).removeClass("foo").addClass("bar").off('click');
    } else {
         $(externalLink).addClass("bar");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) this way you are sure the item is there before you bind it

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " +
      xhr.responseText );
  }
});
```

Comment: Great starting point... I can remove classes, but not run my function for some reason. Please see edited code

Comment: I had to include the code from kinetickLinkFix() inside the ajax complete handler... I couldn't use the function name for some reason.